# Unable to use `--lsi` flag with jekyll in a github action

Tags: jekyll, github-actions, jekyll-extensions

I've been using github actions to automate my build and upload process for a while now. Recently however the builds started failing. The error messaged claimed classifier-reborn was not installed. The image below shows that it definietly is. Could someone provide some assistance please.

[image]